# VB.NET Pass Variable To Another Form in Private Sub

Tags: vb.net

This is part of my code :

```
Private Sub LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(MyCityPath + LoginUsername.Text) Then
        'Some code here......
        'This is not completed
    End If
End Sub
```

The part is not completed. What I have to do is to create variable that can pass to another form. However, this is in a private sub.

Will I be able to use public class in it? How can I pass the variable to another form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options. These examples are assuming that you are passing a string to another form. If not, change the type to whatever you need.  Here are a couple that should get you through most of what you need:

*Place a public field on the other form*

Code of this form:

```
Private Sub LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(MyCityPath + LoginUsername.Text) Then
        'Some code here......
        MySecondForm.Target = "Something special"
    End If
End Sub
```

Code of another form (called `MySecondForm` in the example above):

```
'...
Public Target As String
'...
```

*Put the value directly into a control on the other form*

```
Private Sub LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(MyCityPath + LoginUsername.Text) Then
        'Some code here......
        ' Assumes there is a Textbox named Textbox1 on a form named MySecondForm
        MySecondForm.Textbox1.Text = "Something special"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what does public form mean?

Comment: That would be a different form.

Comment: Also take a look at Constructors,u can pass variable to them when creating a new instance of that form/class : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z08e49e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx